# Large Carmichael Number Data

Tags: biginteger

I need a list of Large Carmichael numbers( 10 to 100 digits ). Is there any website which provides such data. It would be more helpful if i can get a list of large odd composite numbers and primes as well.

Answer (score 1):

Did you already try [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/)? Carmichael numbers are [sequence A002997](http://oeis.org/A002997), and from there you can find a link to a [Table of n, a(n) for n = 1..10000](http://oeis.org/A002997/b002997.txt).

Comment: I can generate till that myself on my system. I want the numbers of higher range( 10^50 ).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the first 33: http://oeis.org/search?q=carmichael&language=english&go=Search.

This is generally a good site for sequences.